# Pycharm disable closing brackets and enable autoindent

Tags: pycharm

Recently I've started using Pycharm (I've installed edu version, hoping there will be less "features you can't live without"). Currently I'm struggling with two problems:
1) when I'm typing `[`, pycharm autocomplete my bracket with `[]`. No, if I want `[]` I type "[]", and if I want `[` I wanna type just "[". Similar to any other 'brackets', like `" ' [ { (` etc.

2) Typing `if-else` loop:

```
if something:
    something more  
    #now  want else, so I type...
    else
```

I wonder if Pycharm is smart enough to automatically put `else` in the previous indent, on the same level as `if`?
Maybe there are commonly known options, but English is not my mother language, so I don't know how to name them and find in the Internet. Or maybe I disabled those features somehow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note: I'm using the Pro 5.0 version, not 100% sure you have the same in the Community version.

For #1, you can disable the automatic closing brackets/quotes in the Smart Keys settings, by default enabled:

[image: smart keys settings]

For #2 it indeed automatically indents the `else` properly when you add the final `:` (i.e. when you type the whole `else:`)

Comment: You may also need to uncheck "Surround selection on typing quote or brace", which has an effect that's a variation of what the OP asked about.